# Weird characters behind every single link and images

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, google-analytics

My site http://ilovetaobao.my
If you view page source, almost every single images and links have this in the end of the URL.

**?84d5a9**

For example like http://ilovetaobao.my/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ilovetaobao-logo2.png?8aaf15

I've achieved 95/100 score in Google Page Insight, but today I check again it dropped to 59, and the culprit should be these links.

My plugins:

Akismet

Aqua Page Builder

Contact form 7

Contact form DB

EWWW Image Optimizer

Facebook Like Box

Google Analytics for WordPress

Hello Dolly

Limit Login Attempts

Remove query strings from static resources (Deactivated, but not solving the problem)

TinyMCE Advanced

W3 total Cache

WordPress Importer

WordPress SEO (by Yoast)

WP-Optimize

Comment: I don't see any problem. In any case it is impossible to guess without having access to your site.

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to the default theme. Does it still happen?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Mark Kaplun and toscho, thank you for replying.
I've figured out the culprit, it was caused by W3 Total Cache Plugin setting.

Under Browser Cache, I have to untick this:
Prevent caching of objects after settings change

The weird string before every links is then removed.